# Does a saboteur with Firearms Training qualify for grit feats?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, feat-qualifications

I recently discovered the [saboteur](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/ascension-games-llc/saboteur) class and I'm interested in playing it in a Pathfinder campaign. I'm also interested in the [Firearms Training trick](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/ascension-games-llc/saboteur/saboteur-tricks/firearms-training-ex) :

> Benefit:  The saboteur gains a grit pool (as the gunslinger class feature), except she uses her Intelligence modifier to determine the size of her grit pool. This grit pool does not stack with any other grit pool she may obtain (such as from a gunslinger); only the larger of the two pools can be used. She also gains a single 1st-level deed of her choice from the gunslinger deed class feature.

As my character has an abysmal Wisdom score and a sky-high Intelligence score, this grit pool would obviously be bigger than the gunslinger's grit pool, and I'm not acutually interested in the gunslinger's class features anyway. But is Firearms Training enough to qualify for [grit feats](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/grit-feats) (all have "grit class feature" as a prerequisite) or would I need to take a level in gunslinger or the Amateur Gunslinger feat to qualify ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although this is a 3rd party class, we can still use the general rules that the Pathfinder Development Team has established for issues like this one. As far as the Pathfinder Devs are concerned, if a class feature works more or less identically to another (differently named) class feature, they are effectively the same for everything that matters (prerequisites, etc).

See [this post](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2ln8z?Can-a-Life-Oracle-with-Channeling-take#30) from one of the main devs with regards to the Life Oracle "Channel" ability and if it qualifies people for "Channel Energy" feats:

> So when the cleric class has a header section called "Class Features" and under that is an entry that says "Channel Energy," and the oracle class has a section called "Class Features" and under that is an entry that says "Channel: You can channel positive energy like a cleric," and the paladin class has a section called "Class Features" and under that is an entry that says "Channel Positive Energy (Su): ... she gains the supernatural ability to channel positive energy like a cleric," those all are intended to work the same way, even though they're not given identical names.

Another sign that the "Firearm Training Trick" should be counted as Grit for prerequisites is the [following FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qto), which discusses whether abilities that are renamed in class archetypes still count as their original abilities:

> If the archetype ability says it works like the standard ability, it counts as that ability. If the archetype's ability requires you to make a specific choice for the standard ability, it counts as that ability. Otherwise, the archetype ability doesn't count as the standard ability. **(It doesn't matter if the archetype's ability name is different than the standard class ability it is replacing; it is the description and game mechanics of the archetype ability that matter.)**

I've bolded the section above that matters most to you.

Based on the above two references, I'd say the Firearms Training Trick (which explicitly references working like the Grit class feature) counts as Grit for prerequisites.

Answer (score 1):

RAW, you must have Amateur Gunslinger or the class feature called 'Grit'.

Firearms Training does not include language indicating that it counts as the class feature so it does not.

This could be another case of 3pp language differences and it could be argued that Ascension Games intended you to qualify, but they didn't give a positive yes or no.